# How do I fix this error while adding currency to Data Grid

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a data grid from a text file in windows forms, but I keep receiving a error when I try to display it which I'm not sure how to fix.

The text file I'm using contains this:

1|2020-07-13|a|b|4|Hours|$4.4|$17.6|$19.89

and this is the code I'm using to fill in the data grid:

```
        table.Rows.Clear();
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        string[] values;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            values = lines[i].ToString().Split('|');
            string[] row = new string[values.Length];

            for(int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
            {
                row[j] = values[j].Trim();
            }

            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
```

but whenever I try and run it I keep getting this error message by table.Rows.Add(row);:

System.ArgumentException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <$4.4> in Unit Price Column.  Expected type is Double.'

I really don't understand what's happening so could anyone help me?

Comment: Im guessing its the $.

Comment: Yes `$4.4` is a string value, it can not be converted to double automatically. I think you should have a class with properties to store values from one line of the file. Then you create a list of class. And in for loop you create an object of class and set it's properties from the `values`. You will have to do Double.Parse to get currency values from the string. And add that object to list and then use that list to populate the GridView

Answer (score 0):

> You are trying to pass the character($) together values as double however is not possible to convert it to double. You will receive an exception.

You should create the columns of DatTable according values that  you will receive.

```
DataTable workTable = new DataTable("Test");  

DataColumn workCol = workTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
  
workTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(String));  
workTable.Columns.Add("var1", typeof(String));  
workTable.Columns.Add("var2", typeof(String));
...
```

And after add the row.

Try it.